# Javascript : Get value of first and second slash

Tags: javascript

How do i get first and second slash of a URL in javascript?

URL : `http://localhost:8089/submodule/module/home.html`

Now i want the value `/submodule/module`

Below is the code i have been trying

```
window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/",2))
```

This got me only `/submodule`

```
window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/",window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/")-1))
```

Also this didnt work. Can anyone please guide where i am going wrong.

Comment: `indexOf('/', 2)` does not mean "find the second slash": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work, it take everything exept the last element of `pathname`:

`let result = window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(0,-1).join('/') + '/'`

Only the 1st and 2de item:

`let result = window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(0,2).join('/') + '/'`

Handle path without file :

```
 // ex: /foo/bar/path.html > foo/bar/
 // ex: /foo/bar/ > foo/bar/

 let result = (window.location.pathname[window.location.pathname.length -1] !== '/') ? window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(0,-1).join('/') + '/' : window.location.pathname
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function, for example like this:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8089/submodule/module/home.html';
var parts = url.split('/');

console.log('/' + parts[3] + '/' + parts[4]);
```

The output will be:

> /submodule/module

Comment: @sTg The necessary change to use `window.location` instead of a fixed string shouldn't be too hard... O.o

Comment: @sTg: Sure, this was just an example. You can also use ``window.location``.

Comment: `window.location` is actually a `Location` object, you have to use some specific key like href or pathname.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var pathParts = window.location.pathname.split('/');

var result = `${pathParts[1]}/${pathParths[2]}`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8089/submodule/module/home.html'; //or window.location.pathname
var re = /\/\/.+(\/.+\/.+)\/.+/
re.exec(url)[1];
```

This expression basically says the url is in the format

```
//[anything](/submodule/module)/[anything]
```

and to get everything in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Functional style
`/\/[^/]*\/[^/]*/.exec(window.location.pathname)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression:

```
var url = ...
var part = url.match(/https?:\/\/.*?(\/.*?\/.*?)\/.*/)[1]
```

Explanation:

```
http          Match the group 'http'
s?            Match 1 or 0 's'
:             Match a semicolon
\/\/          Match '//'
.*?           Match anything (non-greedy)
(             Start capturing block (Everything captured will be an array element)
\/*?\/.*?     Something that looks like /.../...
)             End capturing block
\/.*          Something that looks like /...
```

The output of the match method will be an array with 2 elements. The first one is the whole matched string, and the second is the captured group.